# Bing Maps Menu Bug: Position: Absolute/Relative?

Tags: css, bing-maps

We have a strange problem with the new Bing Maps.
When positioning the map in a ***div*** further down on the page, the popup menu (mouse over "birds-eye view") popups up much further down on the page.

Any ideas how we can fix this code to make it work:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //console.debug('Map', ($("#map"))[0]);
            var location = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-8.59838423, 115.33570617,  0),
                map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(($("#map"))[0], {
                    credentials: '<removed credentials>',
                    disableUserInput: false,
                    showCopyright: false,
                    showDashboard: true,
                    showLogo: false,
                    showScalebar: false,
                    mapTypeId:Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.birdseye
                }
            );


            map.setView({
                animate: false,
                center: location,
                zoom: 12
            });

            //map.entities.push(Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location));


          });


      </script>
   </head>
    <body>

        <div style="position: relative;">
            <div style="width:200px; height: 1000px; background: #eee; position: relative;">Some long content</div>
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 300px; "></div>
            </div>
            <div style="width:200px; height: 1000px; background: #eee;">Some long content</div>
     </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I have the exact same scenario. Another problem I have (which I think stems from the same root), is that the `MouseEventArgs.getY()` returned on the `dblclick` event is completely wrong (I am adding a pushpin to the map on double click, and the pushpin is not added at the location I click). This also causes skewed zooming when using the mouse wheel to zoom.

If anyone has a solution to this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Microsoft says this issue is fixed but for my page its not fixed at all. They now make the page jump to the top and then place the menu. However its still not placed in the right position.
See this thread for more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vemapcontroldev/thread/9f505bda-51b2-4545-b6e2-8f5fceedd573#88e76e55-6b8a-4dce-b9ed-698a250ed743

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a DOCTYPE declaration to the top of your document, before the opening  tag, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427624.aspx

(As a side note, I also suggest that you edit your question to remove the "credentials" line - this is your own personal application key that you should try to protect)

Comment: See this page: http://michaelbodekaer.com/temporary/BingBug_position.html
 It is a direct copy of the script you referenced, all I did was adding a div above. 
If you mouse over the menu called "Birdsview", you will see the popup appears below the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this and found that when the menu was triggered before I scrolled down, the menu appeared in its correct position. However, if I first scrolled down the page, the menu would appear off by X pixels, where X is equal to the number of pixels scrolled.

My diagnosis is that Microsoft are calculating the offset from the scrolled viewport (idiotically) rather than the top of the actual page. I think the only way to fix this is for Microsoft to correct their mistake.